# Is it possible to wrap lines when viewing code for a branch in the browser on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

On small screen of a laptop it gets tedious to see code on Azure DevOps when the line length is large.

The workaround I use instead of using the scrollbar located way down below, is to click and drag mouse cursor from the end of line to the right. But this moves the cursor too fast and using the arrow keys is too slow.

Code editors and IDEs we have the ability to wrap lines (Word wrap) when the lines are large .

The code review UI has the option for word wrap. Cannnot find it for viewing code UI.

Is it possible to do that in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, here it is:

**Right-click -> User Preferences -> Enable word wrap**

[image]